# Arquillian tomee remote jacoco code coverage

Tags: jacoco, jboss-arquillian, apache-tomee, jacoco-maven-plugin, tomee-7

I am doing integration test using **Arquillian in TomEE-Plus 7.0.4 remote** and trying to get Code coverage using **Jacoco 0.8.2**. My code coverage is not covered since I am using arquillian-tomee-remote. Since code is not covered not able to take build. I need sample code with has TomEE-plus arquillian remote and Code coverage using Jacoco. I will appreciate if I get any sample working code or sample project.

I used prepare-agent goal which will generate surefireArgLine ( javaagent) and passed the same in surefire plugin. issue here is, I am using remote Tomee and don't know how to generate correct java agent surefireArgLine set to -**javaagent:/home/user/.m2/repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.8.2/org.jacoco.agent-0.8.2-runtime.jar=destfile=/home/user/project/target/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec,append=true,excludes=**/config/*.class:**/util/*Constants.class**

**what is the correct javaagent option for my configuration which will connect to arquillian-remote-tomee ?**

**Jacoco plugin**

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${plugin.maven.jacoco.version}</version>
        <configuration>
            <propertyName>coverageAgent</propertyName>
            <append>true</append>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/config/*.class</exclude>
                <exclude>**/util/*Constants.class</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>pre-unit-test</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <destFile>${sonar.jacoco.reportPath}</destFile>
                    <propertyName>surefireArgLine</propertyName>
                    <append>true</append>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>post-unit-test</id>
                <phase>test</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>report</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <dataFile>${sonar.jacoco.reportPath}</dataFile>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-ut</outputDirectory>
                    <append>true</append>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>check</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>check</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <dataFile>${sonar.jacoco.reportPath}</dataFile>
                    <haltOnFailure>true</haltOnFailure>
                    <rules>
                        <rule>
                            <element>BUNDLE</element>
                            <limits>
                                <limit>
                                    <counter>LINE</counter>
                                    <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                    <minimum>0.99</minimum>
                                </limit>
                                <limit>
                                    <counter>BRANCH</counter>
                                    <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                    <minimum>0.99</minimum>
                                </limit>
                                <limit>
                                    <counter>CLASS</counter>
                                    <value>MISSEDCOUNT</value>
                                    <maximum>0</maximum>
                                </limit>
                            </limits>
                        </rule>
                    </rules>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

**Dependency**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-testng-container</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.config</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-config-api</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-jacoco</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.Alpha10</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.jacoco.agent</artifactId>
    <classifier>runtime</classifier>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <version>${plugin.maven.jacoco.version}</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jacoco/org.jacoco.core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.jacoco.core</artifactId>
    <version>${plugin.maven.jacoco.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomee</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-tomee-remote</artifactId>
    <version>${tomee.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

**Arquillian.xml**

```
<extension qualifier="jacoco">
    <property name="includes">com.demo.*</property>
</extension>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added the proper java agent ( surefireArgLine) to TomEE remote server via catalina opts  in surefire pluggin. it works.

> surefireArgLine - Will be populate by Surefire prepare-agent at runtime.

```
<tomee.catalina_opts> ${surefireArgLine}</tomee.catalina_opts>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set catalina_opts in arquillian.xml for tomee container. Filter it with maven to pass jacoco javaagent and you are done :).

Comment: yes you are correct. I am overriding all arquillian property in maven surefire pluggin.  Could you please address my other TomEE question ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53996746/tomee-arquillian-additional-library-for-hibernate-in-testing). thanks in advance.

Comment: could help me on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54412555/arquillian-tomee-7-1-0-integration-test-code-coverage-issue-with-jacoco

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm not an expert in neither Arquillian nor TomEE, so you might adjust the answer for your purposes.

Anyway, in a nutshell, JaCoCo instruments bytecode in order to provide a coverage report.

Since when Arquillian is used, the actual test execution happens in a TomEE JVM and not in a JVM that actually runs the test suite (probably a CI server or just a build script that runs the test), so configuring JaCoCo on this test machine won't do much, you'll have to configure the server itself.

JaCoCo has a `-javaagent` option for doing this, and this Java Agent will "intercept" the loading of classes by the server and instrument them.

Now, when JaCoCo works, it produces a `jacoco.exec` file that actually contains a coverage report that can be shown later in various ways (jenkins plugin to show coverage, sonar integration whatever).
And this is by far the most used option AFAIK, so if you go with this approach, given the instrumentation really works, after the tests are done, you'll have to find the server on the test machine and download it to the build machine and integrate with CI/Sonar whatever.

However, there are alternative solutions:

[JaCoCo Documentation](https://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/agent.html) states that there are three modes of running an instrumenting Java Agent:

- File System: At JVM termination execution data is written to a local file.
- TCP Socket Server: External tools can connect to the JVM and retrieve execution data over the socket connection. Optional execution data reset and execution data dump on VM exit is possible.
- TCP Socket Client: At startup, the JaCoCo agent connects to a given TCP endpoint. Execution data is written to the socket connection on request. Optional execution data reset and execution data dump on VM exit is possible.

Technically you can just give different parameters to that javaagent so that it will run JaCoCo in one of these modes.

Anyway, we've discussed the first option, but you can also work with TCP configurations if it's required. Of course, here you'll have to handle security concerns (like permission to expose/access the port, etc).

If you work with TCP mode, there is a [Maven Plugin](https://github.com/piczmar/maven-jacoco-remote) that can come in handy. I haven't used it by myself, just googled so I can't comment whether its any good, it has only 2 stars on Github, so probably it's not production ready but maybe you could get some ideas from its source code.

Comment: I understand that testing is running in remote tomee container. I need to know how to configure javaagent for my scenario

Comment: Since I haven't worked with TomEE, I probably won't be able to have much, In a case of Tomcat I think you should add the javaagent definition to the JAVA_OPTS variable (see its startup scripts) and of course chose the mode of jacoco invocation (one of those three). Hopefully our colleagues will provide more precise answer.

Comment: I know, my answer hasn't changed on this, it was just edited by Godin (formatting, naming, etc). Hopefully, people who actually dealt with TomEE and Jacoco can provide a precise solution with real configurations. Have you tried JAVA_OPTS modification? Does it create jacoco.exec files after running the tests (even without more advanced TCP modes)?

Comment: My current configuration create jacoco.exec. But it doesn't connect the remote tomee, since I don't know the javaagent configurtion for remote tomee

Comment: I meant on TomEE server, have you used javaagent in javaopts there? How did you configure it? Please update the question with this information.

Comment: I used prepare-agent goal  which will generate surefireArgLine ( javaagent) and passed the same in surefire plugin. issue here is, I am using remote Tomee and don't know how to generate correct java agent surefireArgLine set to -javaagent:/home/user/.m2/repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.8.2/org.jacoco.agent-0.8.2-runtime.jar=destfile=/home/user/project/target/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec,append=true,excludes=**/config/*.class:**/util/*Constants.class

Comment: I'm confused now... I meant actually tomee script, not maven at all and not a surefire. Jacoco should run on tomee server and not on the jvm that runs the tests... Thats where the coverage data not generated

Comment: I am not expert in remote-tomee. If I use arquillian-tomee-embedded no code changes. I am using arquillian-tomee-remote which is started by arquillian locally , not running in remote machine. Since tomee-embedded is not supporting any tomee classifier ( plus, Microprofile ) i am using tomee-remote. I want to know how to configure javaagent in maven jacco or in surefire pluggin